# What's "|...|" stand for?

Tags: common-lisp

What's the meaning of `:|temp files|` in the following code snippet?

```
(defmethod acceptor-remove-session ((acceptor my-site-acceptor) (session t))
    (declare (ignore acceptor))
    (loop for path in (session-value :|temp files|)
     do
         (ignore-errors (delete-file path))))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Common Lisp, `|...|` may be used to quote characters in a symbol name; it may escape ordinarily disallowed characters such as spaces, and it also disables case conversion.

- `foo` or `:foo` have the `symbol-name` of `"FOO"`
- `|temp files|` or `:|temp files|` have the `symbol-name` of `"temp files"`
- `||` is named `""`, the empty string, which is otherwise impossible to produce

(The colon here has the usual meaning of a keyword symbol (a symbol in the `KEYWORD` package) and is independent of the bars.)

`|...|` is useful when a task lends itself to the use of symbols, but not ones named according to Common Lisp conventions. I would imagine in this case the text "temp files" occurs in the program's output somewhere, or is used for a filename, or some other case where seeing `TEMP-FILES` would be annoying.

Answer (score 4):

`|` is a multiple escape character in Common Lisp symbols:

```
? 'aaBBcc|DDeeFFgg|hhII|jjKK|LL

-> |AABBCCDDeeFFggHHIIjjKKLL|
```

The vertical bar does not need to surround the whole symbol name. It can also escape parts of the symbol.

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp allows symbol names to contain a wide range of characters, such as `?` and `%`, that most languages wouldn't allow in their identifiers. Even then, sometimes a programmer wants a symbol name to contain something beyond what is normally allowed, such as the single space in `|temp files|` in the OP's example. Two pipe (`|`) characters are required to delimit the name of such a symbol. In addition, such pipe-delimited symbol names are case sensitive, unlike undelimited symbol names.